# How does a RTOS like Green Hill Software's INTEGRITY RTOS integrate with automotive grade linux?

Tags: tizen, rtos, greenhills, automotive, automotive-grade-linux

I'm trying to understand the stack for automotive code - I know that Linux/Android can sit on top of it, and so I would presume AGL, but I'm uncertain of the distinction and what framework the RTOS provides as a platform.

Secondary point: Is Tizen, which AGL was originally based on, also an RTOS in the line of Integrity, or moreso just an OS? What is the difference between Tizen and Integrity; are they just competitors, or entirely different layers in the stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Architecturally the two bare little relationship.

[INTEGRITY Multivisor](https://www.ghs.com/products/rtos/integrity_virtualization.html) uses virtualisation to run Linux (or other OS) as a guest OS in a virtual machine in parallel with INTEGRITY RTOS.

[Tizen is a software stack on top of Linux](https://developer.tizen.org/tizen-architecture), akin to Android or perhaps, given its web-app focus, more closely akin to ChromeOS.

Answer (score 2):

Some background first:

- RTOSs for automotive Electronic Control Units (ECUs) follow specific standards like [OSEK/VDX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSEK) or [AUTOSAR Classic](https://www.autosar.org/standards/classic-platform/). These are tiny and certified RTOSs for the safety-critical tasks (e.g. engine control, brake control, etc.). Some examples are [Vector's MICROSAR](https://vector.com/vi_microsar_os_en.html) or [Evidence's ERIKA Enterprise](http://www.erika-enterprise.com/).
- Recently, the automotive domain started looking to operating systems for additional activities like, for example, infotainment systems. The work carried out by [AUTOSAR Adaptive](https://www.autosar.org/standards/adaptive-platform/) as well as the GENIVI association goes towards this direction. These systems can be based on the Linux kernel (e.g. [Tizen](https://www.tizen.org/), Android, etc.)
- Even more recently, the automotive industry started looking to hypervisor-based solutions for running both systems in parallel on the same electronics. There are some commercial hypervisors, as well as some open-source ones (e.g. [Jailhouse](https://github.com/siemens/jailhouse), [Xen](https://www.xenproject.org/)). You might be interested in reading [this whitepaper](https://www.automotivelinux.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2018/06/agl_software_defined_car_jun18.pdf) by AGL. Note that if you are looking for a fully open-source stack, you can run Linux alongside the ERIKA RTOS on the Jailhouse hypervisor on modern SoCs, as explained [here](http://www.erika-enterprise.com/wiki/index.php?title=ERIKA3_on_the_Jailhouse_hypervisor).

Now, to answer your specific question: Tizen belongs to the second category (i.e. infotainment), while Integrity to the first category (although GreenHills can also provide a commercial hypervisor as mentioned in the existing answer).